# What is the best way of creating a 'featured image' in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm relatively new to Django and I'm looking for a way to create a featured image within an image category.

At the moment I have a Show class and a Photo class:

```
class Show(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)
    playwright = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title


class Photo(models.Model):

    show = models.ForeignKey(Show, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default='images/default.png')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.image.name
```

And I'd like to be able to set one photo for each show as the 'featured' image. Of course, I could put a Boolean field in for this, but that runs the risk of having multiple Featured images when there should be only one.
What is the best structure for this? I've had a look around and can't find any tutorial or resource that shows this behavior. I should be able to set this 'featured' setting from the admin panel.

(Also, I'm aware there are gallery apps out there for Django, but this is part of my learning Django, so I'm trying to build this myself.)

EDIT: I'm afraid I was not as clear as I should have been, apologies for that! I mean specifically that one show can have many photos related to it, and that from that pool of photos, one 'featured' image can be selected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking for the OneToOneField!

```
class Photo(models.Model):

   show = models.OneToOneField(Show, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default='images/default.png')

   def __str__(self) -> str:
       return self.image
```

Make sure you also create a Form in forms.py for it and then make sure to validate it in views.py when you register the Show!

in forms.py something like this:

```
Class ShowPhoto(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
      model = Photo
      fields =('show','image')
```

and in Views.py after importing the ShowPhoto form with:

```
from .forms import ShowPhoto
```

something like this in the function referring to the html page:

add the variable:

```
show_pic = ShowPhoto(request.Post)
```

and add the validation when you are validating the form for the show:

```
if form.is_valid() and show_pic.is_valid():
  show = form.save()
  show_picture = show_pic.save(commit=false)
  show_picture.show = show
  show_picture.save()
```

remember to pass it to the context when you render!

and don't forget to add the form to add the picture when you create the show in the html template like:

```
 {{ show_pic.as_p }}
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the response. In retrospect I think my post was not clear, so sorry about that! What I meant was, I upload several photos per show, and then from all the photos with a given show, I can select one to be the 'featured' image.

Comment: alright, so would you need to select between the pictures uploaded, one suited for the show, so that you can display it in some ways along with the show name? what is the final goal?

Comment: Let's say we have a show 'Hamlet', and a show 'Macbeth'. Each has 10 photos associated with them (20 shots total). Of the 10 photos for Hamlet I can select one to be the 'featured' photo -- likewise for Macbeth. This will be the photo that is displayed on the 'Shows' page. This photo and the other 9 will be displayed on the shows Details page when you click through. The featured photo should be selectable from the admin, and default to any of the associated photos. A show with no photos associated would not exist in the final site, but could occur as you make a new show.